# Deploying React App to Heroku / GitHub pages changes styles / CSS

Tags: css, reactjs, github, heroku, responsive

I'm relatively new to coding, but I've made half a dozen full-stack apps and in each I've noticed that whenever I deploy an app to Heroku / GitHub Pages, every single element on the page gets smaller than what they were on my localhost. For example, a Navbar will go from say 50px to 30px. The font size for an element will go from 20px to 12px. I have no idea why, I'm guessing the index file isn't reading the CSS files properly when it's being rendered and defaulting to something, but it's irritating and I can't plan how to style my pages because I don't know what the finished product is going to look like. Does anyone have any sort of answer?

[My portfolio site on localhost: everything is the size I want it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h0aoC.png)

[My portfolio site deployed on GitHub pages: everything is smaller.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d30e8.png)

Comment: if you are on Mac, try "CMD" + "-"

Comment: Try using the Chrome dev-tools to see what is causing the widths to differ.

Answer (score 2):

On localhost you're zoomed in, do you see that icon at the left side of your address bar? Just reset your zoom on localhost with CMD+0, or on PC I guess it's Ctrl+0 and you'll have a consistent look.

Good luck with your site (: